# Ice Cream Sandwich for Samsung GT-S6102B?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-y

I have been looking to see if my device (the Samsung GT-S6102B) supports the new Ice Cream Sandwich Android version, but have found nothing. I thought perhaps more knowledgeable people would be able to answer me, so here I ask: Does my device support the OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, ICS can be put in Samsung Galaxy Y Duos S6102B. Unfortunately, a ready-made ROM featuring ICS for the device isn't available yet.
So, unless you are a ROM cooker & developer, you can't do this.

Comment: Is there an official site where Android ROMs are uploaded? I just want to know if I am running the latest OS I can in my phone.

Comment: @WolterHellmund Manufacturers don't officially publish stock ROMs for users to download. However, you can find info on official website. I have found on Samsung.com that latest official OS for your device is Android 2.3 (Gingerbread).

Comment: Keep your eyes on trusted news sources to discover ICS update quickly. Sometimes, users get Android updates from non-official projects quicker than official one.